# Cakephp 2.5. Auth Basic: Redirect on Unauthorized Error

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am having an API where I use Auth with Basic authentication.
As long as I use the correct username and password, everything goes fine!

Now I went to see what will happen if I try to login with wrong data.

I get the error message:

```
Unauthorized
Error:  The requested address '/api' was not found on this server.
```

Is there anything I can do, that I can return a

```
$this->response->statusCode(401);
```

instead of anything other?
I thought I had a else condition, but the one (see below) is not getting called... 
I don't know why...

my code look like this:

```
  var $components = array('Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'api',
        'action' => 'login'
    ),
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Basic' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Appuser'
        )
    )));


public function login() {
$this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->Appuser->id = AuthComponent::user('id');

        // save last login
        $this->Appuser->saveField('last_login', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        return $this->response->body(json_encode('Hello :-) You are in!'));
    }else{
        return $this->response->body(json_encode(array('ERROR' => array('file' => basename(__FILE__), 'line' => __LINE__, 'msg'=> 'Login failed!'))));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try unauthorizedRedirect :

```
AuthComponent::$unauthorizedRedirect
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authcomponent-api

Comment: While the answer is contained in the link, the answer also contains the keywords that a web search could contain should the link break.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct response, but in my application I made something like this, hope it can help you :

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'projets', 'action' => 'index', 'admin'=>true),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'admin'=>false, 'intro'),
        'loginError' => "Les informations d'identification sont incorrectes.",
    )
);
```

Comment: As I want to connect from a mobile device to the api, I don't need those redirects, as long as I login with correct data. I wonder why I get this Unauthorized instead of getting the else from the $this->Auth->login() function. The problem is now, that my device receives the whole bunch of html response where the Unauthorized is shown. In such a case I want to rendering of anything and just a simple return message, saying that the login failed...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it out:

first of all I had to add into my API

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }
```

Then I followed this tutorial: 
http://chetan4cake.blogspot.de/2012/06/exception-handling-in-cakephp-20.html

And in app/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php

I added

```
public function notAuth($error) {
        $this->controller->beforeFilter();
        $this->controller->response->send(401);
    }
public function unauthorized($error) {
        $this->notAuth($error);
    }
```

This way I get on every function of my API a 401 error when trying to get in with wrong data and when I call directly the login function I set the "else" of the if($this->Auth->login()) to $this->response->statusCode(401);